# Eclipse Plugin: How can I tell the plugin to open a new Editor every time instead of switching the focus to an existing Editor?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In my Plugin there is an action to open an Editor (extends EditorPart). When I try to open it a second time, its init method isn't called. Instead the focus is shifted to the editor that is already open.

The Editor is associated with a filetype. Here is the excerpt from the plugin.xml:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editor
        class="de.blub.tool.ide.editors.GRASPEditor"
        default="true"
        extensions="grasp"
        filenames="*.grasp"
        icon="icons/newGraspFile.png"
        id="de.blub.tool.ide.editors.GRASPEditor"
        name="GRASP File Editor">
    </editor>
</extension>
```

I have an Action to open a new Editor. When I try to click that Action twice it reuses the first Editor. I also tried to use an EditorMatcher that implements `IEditorMatchingStrategy` and always returns false in its matches() method. Even that doesn't change the behavior.

This seems to be a desired/default behavior in eclipse. How can I change that so that the user can initialize a new Editor each time?

Comment: That definition should open a new editor for each file and only reuse an existing editor if that particular file is already open - is that not what you want?

Comment: Note: `filenames` doesn't support `*` and isn't necessary here anyway.

Comment: Since the matching strategy doesn't work I don't think there is any way to open a new editor if an existing editor is open for the file.

Comment: I think it is because of the equal method in a class that implements `IEditorInput`, but I have to evaluate that further.

Comment: The editor input will generally be `org.eclipse.ui.part.FileEditorInput`, there is no way to change that or to change its equals method.

Comment: Yes there is a way. In my case EditorPart.getEditorInput() returns an instance of my custom class that implements IEDitorInput. Setting the equal method in that class to always return false kind of solves the issue. At least it allows to open new editors. But it leads to other wrong behaviors.

Comment: Overriding that method and returning the wrong editor input will cause chaos. Eclipse expects that method to return the editor input that it gave to the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse looks for the `equals` method of the `IEditorInput` instance. The Editor somewhere in its code (in my case in the `doSave` method) uses a `setInput` method like this:

```
@Override
public void init(IEditorSite site, IEditorInput input) throws PartInitException {
    // Initialize the editor input
    this.input = new MyInputClass(resource);
    ...
}

@Override
public void doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
    ...
    setInput(input);
}
```

`MyInputClass` is the class that extends `IEditorInput`. The logic for eclipse to reuse an Editor or create a new one is in its `equals` method. The following example checks the path of an IResource field:

```
public class MyInputClass implements IEditorInput {
    private IResource resource;

    public MyInputClass(IResource resource) {
         this.resource = resource;
    }

    public IResource getResource() {
        return resource;
    }

    public void setResource(IResource resource) {
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj instanceof MyEditorClass) {
            MyEditorClass other = (MyEditorClass) obj;
            if (getResource().getFullPath().equals(other.getResource().getFullPath())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Of course one can define another logic inside the equals method. Make sure to not create a chaos, which is very well possible, as greg-449 pointed out in a comment.